# Read data from a file into struct and add struct to a vector (to create a vector of structs)

Tags: c++

This question has been asked before but the other question/answers used concepts I'm not yet familiar with in C++.

I need to read data from a file into a vector of structs.

I have the following code but I'm confused about what to put in (....), that is if I have the correct logic.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct Parts{
        std::string partNum;
        char partClass;
        int stock;
        float cost;
};

bool readFile(std::vector <Parts>&);
int displayMenu();

int main(){
        std::vector <Parts> pVector;

        readFile(pVector);

        if (!readFile(pVector)){
                std::cout << "Error reading file!" << std::endl;
        }
        else{
                displayMenu();
        }
        return 0;
}

bool readFile(std::vector <Parts> &pVector){
        std::ifstream inputFile("parts.txt");
        if (inputFile.fail()){
                std::cout << "Error reading file!" << std::endl;
                return false;
        }
        else{
                while (....){
                        pVector.emplace_back(....);
                }
                return true;
        }
}
```

Sample lines from the file:

```cpp
P-42936 A 18 129.79
P-43179 A 47 35.60
P-43264 B 31 103.81
P-43367 B 5 32.39
P-43378 A 46 6.38
P-43622 A 10 155.36
```

Comment: cin >> xxxx is what you are looking for

Comment: If that's the case then congratulations! You're one up on Bono. He STILL hasn't found what he's looking for.

Comment: _"This question has been asked before but the other question/answers used concepts I'm not yet familiar with in C++."_ What were they? Otherwise we'll just be prone to repeating things useless to you? Or perhaps a good opportunity to learn those concepts!

Comment: @user4581301 lol, I appreciate that reference :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  The previous answer used defining the ```operator >>``` in Bruno's explanation below, but I wanted to understand the more primitive (and in this case, what my professor would be expecting from us based on what we've learned in class so far) method first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want that :

```
bool readFile(std::vector <Parts> &pVector){
  std::ifstream inputFile("parts.txt");

  if (inputFile.fail()){
    std::cout << "Error reading file!" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  else {
    Parts part;

    while (inputFile >> part.partNum >> part.partClass >> part.stock >> part.cost)
      pVector.emplace_back(part);
    return true;
  }
}
```

In *main* you call two time the read function :

> ```
>    readFile(pVector);
>
>    if (!readFile(pVector)){
> ```

very probably the first call must be removed

It can be also interesting to define the `operator >>` for *Parts* rather than to have the code doing that in *readFile*

So :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct Parts{
  std::string partNum;
  char partClass;
  int stock;
  float cost;
};

std::istream & operator >>(std::istream & is, Parts & part) {
  if (is >> part.partNum >> part.partClass >> part.stock)
    is >> part.cost;

  return is;
}

bool readFile(std::vector <Parts>&);
//int displayMenu();

int main(){
  std::vector <Parts> pVector;

  if (!readFile(pVector)){
    std::cout << "Error reading file!" << std::endl;
  }
  else{
    //displayMenu();
    // to check, of course operator << can be defined too
    for (auto p : pVector)
      std::cout << p.partNum << '/' << p.partClass << '/' << p.stock << '/' << p.cost << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

bool readFile(std::vector <Parts> &pVector){
  std::ifstream inputFile("parts.txt");

  if (inputFile.fail()){
    std::cout << "Error reading file!" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }
  else {
    Parts part;

    while (inputFile >> part)
      pVector.emplace_back(part);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall r.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat parts.txt 
P-42936 A 18 129.79
P-43179 A 47 35.60
P-43264 B 31 103.81
P-43367 B 5 32.39
P-43378 A 46 6.38
P-43622 A 10 155.36
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
P-42936/A/18/129.79
P-43179/A/47/35.6
P-43264/B/31/103.81
P-43367/B/5/32.39
P-43378/A/46/6.38
P-43622/A/10/155.36
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest adding overloads for `operator>>` and `operator<<`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Part {            // I renamed it because it only holds info about one part
    std::string partNum;
    char partClass;
    int stock;
    float cost;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Part& p) {
    return is >> p.partNum >> p.partClass >> p.stock >> p.cost;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Part& p) {
    return os << p.partNum << ' ' << p.partClass << ' ' << p.stock << ' ' << p.cost;
}
```

This makes extracting or printing one `Part` easy:

```
bool readFile(std::vector<Part>& pVector){
    std::ifstream inputFile("parts.txt");
    if(inputFile) {
        Part tmp;
        while(inputFile >> tmp)        // extract one Part at a time using operator>>
            pVector.emplace_back(tmp);
        return true;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error reading file!" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}
```